Explanation needed for my result
I am new to string handling in SQL server and was wondering what makes the below code return the result it returns. Could I please have a detailed explanation?
My code:
Select CAST(CAST(CAST('08' as nvarchar) as varbinary) as varchar) as [result]

Output:

| Result |
|   0    |

What is happening here from '08' being converted to nvarchar to varbinary to varchar??

The result you get is likely different based on the application you are using. SSMS and ADS will give different results, for examples due to the different way they handle null characters.

CAST('08' as nvarchar) does seem odd though; it could be abbreviated to N'08'.

SELECT CAST('08' AS varbinary), result is 0x3038, this is ASCII code or ANSI code.
SELECT CAST(N'08' AS varbinary), CAST(CAST('08' AS nvarchar) AS varbinary) result is 0x30003800   0x30003800, it's UNICODE, that means, when you CAST a char to nchar, SQL SERVER will change it's binary structure to fit character standards.
SELECT CAST(0x30003800 AS varchar), it will return 0, because the first byte 0x30 is ASCII char '0', the next byte 0x00 is ASCII char 'null', it cannot be shown and always be treat as a control symbol means end of string, so the display will be cutoff. Add another CAST outter your expression, SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST( CAST('08' as nvarchar) AS varbinary) AS varchar) AS varbinary), you will see 0x30003800, every bytes you convert from nvarchar are there.
What confuses you is the char to nchar conversion, which changes the binary data.

"so the display will be cutoff." That's completely dependent on the application. Some treat a null character as an EoF marker, while others do not. For example, ADS displays 08.

@ThomA Yes, you're right. It should be "When it is displayed in the results window of SSMS, it will be cutoff." It really depends.
